# How to strech Button's ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a **Button** like this:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TEXT}" FontWeight="Bold"
DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NUMBER}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

And it looks like this: `(deliberately removed styling code)`

[image]

I want that the `DockPanel` streches inside the `Button`. When i use `XAML's Live Debugger` is see the following:

[image]

So i need to stretch this `Content Presenter` of Button to fill all of the Buttons inner area (e.g. to stretch).

How can i do that ?

Comment: Wouldn't you just set the DockPanel to Stretch?

Comment: I already tried that. It's not working, because the ContentPresenter does not strech. s. in XAML-Debugger image

Comment: What exatly do you mean with stretch? Up/Down-Scaling of fontsize? Have you tried `Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`?

Comment: You would have to edit the template of the button.

Comment: So for this specific example unless there's something missing. There's no reason for using `DockPanel` and both those string bindings could be in a single TextBlock using inline Run's which would also allow it fill the Button the way you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of @lokusking works and looks like this:

```
<Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

Another solution I found online is here:

https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/02/24/stretching-content-in-an-expander-header/

In my case the DockPanel looks like this:

```
<DockPanel Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=ActualWidth}">
```